# Paginação ajax via servidor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-datatables

Preciso fazer uma paginação via servidor só que via `Ajax`. Abaixo estou postando o grid de como estou fazendo, mas preciso pegar os valores dinamicos e não sei como fazer, segue o grid

```
function drawTable(habilita) {
dataTable = $('#tabFiltra').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bSearchable": false,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bRetrieve": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "query/getQuery",
    "aoColumns": [{ "bVisible": habilita }, null, null, null, null, null, null],
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 250], [5, 10, 15, 25, 50, 100, 250]],
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "Processando...",
        "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords": "Não foram encontrados resultados",
        "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",
        "sInfoPostFix": "",
        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
        "sUrl": "",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst": "«« Primeiro",
            "sPrevious": "« Anterior",
            "sNext": "Seguinte »",
            "sLast": "Último »»"
        }
    },
    "fnServerData": listaPassagensMes(1, 25, 9)

});
```

}

Como faço para pegar esse valor na grid :

```
"iDisplayLength"
```

E mesmo como faço para passar os outros sem chumbar no código ?

Comment: Não sei se entendi errado, mas se a dúvida é sobre a função `dataTable` do jQuery, recomendo incluir a tag [tag:jquery], para dar melhor visibilidade e ficar organizada.

Comment: A sua pergunta está pouco clara. Você fala em AJAX sem especificar se já consegue ir buscar a informação que precisa ao servidor. Pode esclarecer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assim o que você pode fazer é setar uma variável com valores vindos de um input, select e afins algo tipo assim:

```
variavelValor = $('#idCampoAondeVemoValor').val();

"iDisplayLength": variavelValor,
```

Como disse é muito prático de fazer e não fica "chumbado" no código

Espero ter ajudado